# How to detect some part of string from one element in list and other part from another element in list?

Tags: python, string, list

```
upload = ['wish you happy birthday','take care','good night']

string = 'happy birthday take'
```

expected is :: `{'happy birthday':0,'take':1}   ## 0 and 1 are index of list`

Comment: So you want to detect and count any part of `string` and count it in `upload`? How do you define the parts you want to count? Is it combinations of full words, or just any string (including single letters)?

Comment: What if there is ```happy``` in ```upload``` list? What is the Output ?

Answer (score 0):

Brute force method:

1. Initially generate n*(n-1) combinations of the elements from the
   list and store them in a 2-D array.
2. Then search for subsequent substring matches (or string matches) for
   the required string from the previously generated 2-D array.
3. Index of generated string cell matching with the required string
   gives expected result.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, a critical thing here is to find the longest possible match for your word combinations. Therefore I would go with a recursion to check how many words after each other can be found in upload:

```
upload = ['wish you happy birthday','take care','good night']
search_string = 'foo happy birthday take care bar good night good'

words = search_string.split()
len_word = len(words)
result = dict()

def findWordInUpload(search_str, upld):
    for j, u in enumerate(upld):
        if u.find(search_str) > -1:
            return j
    return -1

next_idx = 0
for i, w in enumerate(words):
    if i < next_idx:
        continue
    var_len = 1
    search_substr_new = w
    temp_res = -1
    while findWordInUpload(search_substr_new, upload) > -1:
        search_substr = search_substr_new      
        temp_res = findWordInUpload(search_substr, upload)
        if i + var_len < len_word:
            var_len += 1
            search_substr_new = " ".join(words[i:i + var_len])
        else:
            break
    
    if temp_res > -1:
        result[search_substr] = temp_res
    next_idx = i + var_len - 1

print(result)
```

With the aforementioned search string it outputs `{'happy birthday': 0, 'take care': 1, 'good night': 2, 'good': 2}` is it what you`re looking for?

EDIT: simplified the whole var_len thing (redundancies in first version)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools`:

```
import itertools

upload = ['wish you happy birthday','take care','good night']
string = 'happy birthday take'.split(' ')

combine = []    # combinations

for u in range(1, len(string)):
    for i in itertools.permutations(string, u):
        combine += [" ".join(list(i))]
print(combine)

result = {}
for count, words in enumerate(upload):
    for strings in combine:
        if strings in words:
            result[strings] = count

remove = []
# remove duplicate combinations
# e.g. if 'happy birthday' exist, remove 'happy' and 'birthday'
for items in result:
    if len(items.split(" ")) > 1:
        for u in items.split(" "):
            if u in result and u not in remove:
                remove += [u]
                
print(remove)
for items in remove:
    del result[items]

print(result)
```

output:

```
['happy', 'birthday', 'take', 'happy birthday', 'happy take', 'birthday happy', 'birthday take', 'take happy', 'take birthday']
['happy', 'birthday']
{'happy birthday': 0, 'take': 1}
```